# Create a method that will replace all repeating characters with a given character. Method signature will be replaceRepeating(String, char)

Tags: string, replace

Create a method that will replace all repeating characters with a given character. Method
signature will be replaceRepeating(String, char). For example, if I invoke
replaceRepeating(“Krishnan Aravind”, ‘*’), the output should be “K**sh*** ***v**d”. The
repeating characters are r, i, n and a. They all have been replaced with *

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to solve this problem.

---

The one that seems pretty common to me would be using a hash table. The exact name for the data structure will depend on the programming language you are using. Ex - `unordered map` in c++.
The peculiarity of this data structure is that the time complexity of insertion, removal, and deletion operations is O(1).
Let's look at the algorithm
Your Map will have characters as keys and their count as value for that key in the hashtable.
Iterate over the whole string and store the characters and their counts as key-value pairs. 
Iterate again over the string. This time for each character, look at its count from the hostable. If the count exceeds one, then replace it with the character that is passed in the second argument of your `replaceRepeating` function.

You can google the implementation details. Here is the link for c++ 
[unordered map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unordered_map-in-cpp-stl/)

Comment: Using HashMap or HashTable we can solve this problem. but without using any Collection or inbuilt library -- How we can solve it

Comment: You can use the simple array. Just make an array of size 256 for each character. Each character will be indexed by its ASCII value. The value at the ith index will represent its count. If the case is limited to only alphabets then the size can be reduced to 52(26 for small letters and 26 for capital ones.')

Comment: Also, I'd not suggest using a naive method here. With that, no new space is needed but time complexity will become O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks,I have resolved this issue with help of HashMap

Comment: Then you can close your question or accept the answer.